# How to Print a partial text from a given text using sed

Tags: sed

How to print partial text from the following input file using sed ?

Input data file

```
ABC mobile - ABC, Inc
XYZ123 mobile - XYZ123 company
TD Ameritrade Mobile Trader - TD Ameritrade Mobile, LLC
```

Expected Output

```
ABC, Inc
XYZ123 Company
TD Ameritrade Mobile, LLC
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just delete everything up to a dash and space:

```
sed 's/.*- //'
```

Answer (score 1):

Apparently you want to print everything from `-`:

For this you can use `cut`:

```
$ cut -d'-' -f2 file
 ABC, Inc
 XYZ123 company
 TD Ameritrade Mobile, LLC
```

But it is showing the leading space after the dash. So it is better to go for `awk`:

```
$ awk -v FS="- " '{print $2}' file
ABC, Inc
XYZ123 company
TD Ameritrade Mobile, LLC
```

`-v FS="- "` sets the field separator as `-` (note the space) and then `{print $2}` prints the second block.

Or `sed`:

```
$ sed 's/^[^-]*- //' file
ABC, Inc
XYZ123 company
TD Ameritrade Mobile, LLC
```

`^[^-]*-` matches everything from the beginning of the line (`^`) up to the first dash and then a space. Then it replaces it with an empty string, so in fact it is deleting everything up to `-`.

Answer (score 1):

using back reference :

```
sed 's/.*-\(.*\)/\1/'
```